# Istio installation on VM's

Tags: istio-sidecar

has anyone did successfully install Istio on VirtualMachine and created workloadEntry?

My istio-ingressgateway is exposed as type LoadBalancer(AWS Nlb) on private_subnets.

On Virtual Machine the sidecar.env config file has has the default discoveryAddress as istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, is it possible to configure it with DNS name not an IP?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no. Because the `pilot-agent` on the VM first needs to communicate with Istiod (in k8s) to complete a series of initialization work, after which the [DNS resolution in the pilot-agent](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/dns-proxy/) will work properly.